# UWP (Desktop Bridge) App and User Downloadable Executables

Tags: uwp, exe, desktop-bridge

We are currently in the process of converting our application to UWP (Via DesktopBridge) and have so far had no issues, however we support custom executables that users can create to extend the functionality.  These download ok from within the application, but when we attempt to execute them we get an LP5 error.

Because of the nature of these files we cannot add them to the appxmanifest or download them as ExtensionPacks from the AppStore.

Is there a workaround for this that we can use? or has anyone found a solution that could come in handy

As usual any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: What is an "LP5 error"?

Comment: Very good question,  the full text of a dialog box that pops up is... "Error while unpacking program, code LP5. Please report to author.".  Now i am the author and can vouch that no packing tools were used on it.

Comment: Where do you download and unpack them to? (what file path?)

Comment: We download them to the virtualized folder under "(user)/AppData/Local" but of course outside of the UWP sandbox they are in a different location.  As stated we don't pack (or unpack) anything.  Its just an exe generated inside VisualStudio.

Comment: One thing of note though, is that I copied notepad.exe from the window's folder into the virtual address space of the UWP application and ShellExecute from within the App on that file did exactly the same thing of throwing an LP5 (Unpack) error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your app writes files (content or executables) to the AppData folder, those writes will be redirected to a per-app/per-user location under %userprofile\AppData\Local\Packages{PackageFamilyName}. This is documented here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-behind-the-scenes

You have a couple of option to accomplish this scenario in your app:

1) ShellExecute your files from the redirected location

2) Use the modern ApplicationData API for both read and write and you won't need to know about the actual location: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Storage.ApplicationData

3) Use a different location that is not redirected, such as %temp%

One general note on your scenario: executing dynamically downloaded binaries is not supported on devices in Win10S Mode. Only store-signed code can be executed on those.

Comment: Ok that works, it seems that the virtualization of the folders when in UWP sandbox mode is causing incorrect launch folders for dependencies.

Comment: However that leaves one question, how do I work out / get the path to the 'real' folder and not the virtualized one from inside the application?

Comment: Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalCacheFolder returns the real path.